# How to assign a single object to a list?

Tags: xamarin

I'm working with an API rest and it returns me two types of json, object and array.

Object(When there is only one record in the database):

```
{ "complain": { "id": "1" , "description": "hello", "date": "2017-01-24 11:46:22", "Lat": "20.5204446", "Long": "-100.8249097" } }
```

Array(When there is more than one record in the database):

```
{ "complain": [ { "id": "1" , "description": "hello", "date": "2017-01-24 11:46:22", "Lat": "20.587446", "Long": "-100.8246490" }, { "id": "2" , "description": "hello 2", "date": "2017-01-24 11:50:12", "Lat": "20.529876", "Long": "-100.8249097" } ] }
```

The code I use to consume the json is as follows:

```
content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var token = JToken.Parse(content);

                if (token["complain"] is JArray)
                {
                    var jsonArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootArray>(content);
                }
                else if (token["complain"] is JObject)
                {
                    var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);
                }
```

When it comes to a json array if I can add it to a listview:

```
myList.ItemsSource = jsonArray.listArray;
```

But if it is an object I can not and I get the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type Object to IEnumerable.

Comment: That is because `list` at that point is a `RootObject`, add that object to a List/Array/Collection and then assign that collection to your `ItemSource`

Comment: Do you have any control over the api? If you do I would recommend you do not return 2 different objects from the same end point. It should always return back  an array even if there is only one record in the database. It should stop you from having to do these checks.

Comment: Your post is an observation. What's the question? :-) How to assign a single object to a list? How to change the Json to make it work? How to change the RESTful API to return something different? Or just: why is it not working?

Comment: Yes, my question is, How to assign a single object to a list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to solve my error, it was just a matter of creating a list and adding the deserialized json object.

```
var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);
List<Complain> simpleList = new List<Complain>();
simpleList.Add(jsonObject.ComplainObject);
myList.ItemsSource = simpleList;
```

The class to deserialize the Json object:

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("complain")]
    public Complain ComplainObject { get; set; }
}
```